# Filter two models django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have two similar models:

```
class Boat(models.Model)
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Enter a Boat name")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time']

class Car(models.Model)
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Enter a Boat name")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time']
```

For example, there are 3 objects of the car model:

| Name | Created |
| --- | --- |
| Nissan Almera | 02/2/2020 |
| Renault Logan | 01/9/2020 |
| Mitsubishi L200 | 03/24/2021 |

and 1 one object of the boat model:

| Name | Created |
| --- | --- |
| wooden boat | 01/01/2021 |

Is it possible to make a filter that would display the 3 most recently created objects? i.e wooden boat, mitsubishi L200  and renault Logan

Comment: TLDR; No; Long answer - it is possible, but require some hacks, e.g. create aggratation model OR create common model to Car and Boat OR create logs about creating model

Comment: I would advise to work with model inheritance here. You first define a model "item" or something similar, and then you cvan let `Car` and `Boat` inherit from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it is possible. Maybe there are many to do this. I'm using this solution for a long time. you can try this.

Example:

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter

bots = Boat.objects.all()
cars = Car.objects.all()
bot_cars = sorted(chain(bots, cars), key=attrgetter('time'), reverse=True)[:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If these two models will always have same fields, its probably best to use a separate model Type to which your Object model has a ForeignKey relationship. You can also use choice fields if the types are not dynamic i,e only Boat and Car

Example TypeModel:

```
class Type(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Example ObjectModel:

```
class Object(models.Model)
    type = models.ForeignKey(to=Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time']
```

Now, you just need to query on one single model. I am suggesting this to avoid redundant model definitions
As for the help_text you can dynamically handle the help text depending on the chosen type in your template file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily like this:

```
 Boat.objects.all().union(Car.objects.all(), all=True).order_by('time').limit(3).values("name")
```

Union is similar to the SQL UNIION operator